# Binding - UpdateSource when using a behaviour

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, attachedbehaviors

I have a behaviour I've written that binds to my ViewModel to get a particular value. I want to explicitly update the source when the behaviour's Associated object loses focus, however I cannot access the binding to execute UpdateSource on the behaviour as the behaviour is not a framework element (of course).
I have thought about creating a new binding in code when the behvaiour attaches and keeping a reference to it but wondered if there may be a better method.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access binding expressions in MVVM pattern or in Silverlight 2.0. 
In silverlight 3 and 4, you would have to get into Attached Behavior. Attached behavior recieves the ui element as an input and then you can get its binding expression from the ui element.

```
     var bnexp = YourUIElement.GetBindingExpression(YourAttachedBehaviorClass.YourAttachedDependencyProperty);
     bnexp.UpdateSource();
```

... Let me know if this helps

Comment: This might work in WPF but Silverlight doesn't have a `GetBindingExpression` method.

Comment: I guess this is present in Silverlight 3... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getbindingexpression%28vs.96%29.aspx

Comment: K, I wasn't specific enough, There is no `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression` in Silverlight.  As the OP alluded to a Behaviour is not a `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: Thx for the hint. I have made necessary ammendmends to my reply.